# Django field with foreignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, modelchoicefield

I'm using `Django v4.1` and have a [foreignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) relationship I want to pull into a form.

The two models:

```
class Service(models.Model):
   client = models.ForeignKey("Client", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
   # some other fields
```

and

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # a few more fields
```

The form:

```
class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = "__all__"
```

However, in the front-facing form, "Client" is generated, but without a `SELECT` field.

There is another model with a foreignKey relationship to Client, order:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey("Client", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    # more fields...
```

And it's form:

```
class OrderModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = "__all__"
```

Which renders as expected with a `SELECT` field for the `Client`.

Looking at the [forms docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) I experimented with (importing `Client` from `models` and) adding a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField),
(`"client": forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Client.objects.all())` both inside and outside of a `widgets` dict), but based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21165052/2223106) I'm thinking Django should be rendering that on it's own, as it is for `Order`.

Please share suggestions in debugging. Thanks much.

Comment: Normally it indeed is a `ModelChoiceField` by default. Is the `ServiceForm` complete?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not sure what you mean. The entire code for the form is above. In the front end, all the fields are displayed, but `Client` doesn't have a field. Just a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

Even though I've been managing this project for a while, there are a lot of gaps in my Django knowledge. So I made a [new Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01) and [app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial02), adding a `myapp/models.py` with a minimized version of the problem app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey("Client", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)


class Service(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey("Client", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Sure enough, the `SELECT` fields were there for `Client` in both `Service` and `Order` views.

The barebones app *doesn't even have* a `forms.py` file in it, so I thought, what if I remove my `ServiceForm(ModelForm)` (from the real project) altogether?

But this raised an Exception because `admin.py` is importing `ServiceForm` from forms.

Hmmm. I hadn't thought to look in `class ServiceAdmin`.

#### Lo and behold:

```
readonly_fields = (
    "client",
    etc...
)
```

Removed that line and the `SELECT` field is there as expected.